# C++ multiple values initialization

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

I am writing a program in C++. I am having a problem with the code when I assign multiple values to a single variable. I am confused about the particular logic as there is no decrement operator in the code but when `i` assign the multiple values its logic is not completely understood by me:

```
int main()
{
    int j = 1;
    int i = (j+2, j+3, j++);
    cout<<"value is "<<i;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Output is `1`. I don't know one is assigned to `i`.

Comment: That's not assigning multiple values to a single variable, it's not possible. You need to read about the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Comment: The comment by Joachim says it all.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `int i=(j+2,j+3,j++);`, it's basically like you wrote `int i=j++;`.

That means:

1) since the value of `j` is 1, `i` will have the same value;

2) after that line `j` will be incremented.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you cannot do what you want to do, and the comma operator is coming into play. To be crystal clear, this line:

```
int i=(j+2,j+3,j++);
```

Is performing these steps:

> 1. j+2 is evaluated. This evaluates to 3, which is discarded as it is not assigned to anything.
> 2. j+3 is evaluated, see step 1.
> 3. j++ is evaluated. This increments j, whose value becomes 2, but evaluates to the OLD value of j, which is 1.
> 4. The result of step 3 is assigned to i.

Answer (score 0):

variable j is post increment so the current value of j is put into i and then j is incremented.

You can think of this as being:

```
int j=1;
int temp = j + 2;
int temp1 = j + 3;
int i=j;
j++;
```

Where the variables `temp` and `temp1` do not really exist and are thrown away.

Comment: int i=(j++,j+2,j+3); i got your point but why the answer will become 5 instead of 4 in this case.

Comment: Because j=1; then j++; then i = j+3;  so j=1 then j = 2 then i = 2 + 3;

Answer (score 0):

Read: [Comma Operator: `,`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs06xbxh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> The comma operator `,` has `left-to-right associativity`. Two expressions
>   separated by a comma are evaluated left to right. The left operand is
>   always evaluated, and all side effects are completed before the right
>   operand is evaluated.

The expression:

```
i = (j + 2, j + 3, j++);
```

is in effects equivalent to (because evaluation of `j + 2` and `j + 3` has no side-effects):

```
i = j++;
```

So first value of `j` is assigned to `i` that is 1  then `j` incremented to `2`.
Here `j + 2` and `j + 3` are evaluated before `j++` but it has no effect.

Important to note parenthesis `( )` in expression over write the precedence so first `,` operator evaluated within parenthesis  and then `=` evaluates at last.

To understand the output: [look at precedence table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/126fe14k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) `,` have lower precedence than `=`. In you expression you have overwrite the precedence using parenthesis.

**Edit**: on the basis of comments:

Suppose if expression is:

```
int i = (j++, j+2, j+3);
```

In this expression `j++`  first increase value  of `j` because of `++` operation to `2` then `j + 2` evaluates but this sub-expression has no side effects finally `j + 3` evaluates = `5` and `5` is assigned to `i`. so value to `i` at the end is `5`.

[Check working code](http://codepad.org/4XEUxlQE)

So here `int i =(j++, j+2, j+3);`  is NOT equivalent to just `i = j + 3` because `j++` has side effect that change value of `j`.

In sort if you have an expression like `a = (b, c, d)` then first expression `b` evaluates then expression `c` evaluates  then expression `d` evaluates due to left-to-write associativity of  `,` operator then final value of expression `d`  is assigned to variable `a`.

Comment: int i=(j++,j+2,j+3); but when we are dealing with this then why the answer of our question becomes 5. as it should be 4 according to particular logic

Comment: @user3102208 this is equivalent  to  `i = j + 3`

Comment: I've read it but as j=1  and as you say i=j+3; so i should be 4 according to this. butt its not so its 5.

Comment: @user3102208 Instead try yourself,  According to your expression `int i = (j++, j+2, j+3);` (in first comment) if `j = 1`  first `j++` incremented to `2` then because of `i = j + 3`,  `i`  will be **5**

Comment: @user3102208 Read last statement in answer I think that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Let consider these definitions

```
int j=1;
int i=(j+2,j+3,j++);
```

(j+2,j+3,j++) is an expression with the comma operator. Its result is the last subexpression. Subexpressions j + 2 and j + 3 do not influence neither j nor i. The only subexpression that influence  j and i is the last. It is j++. The value of postincrement operator is the value of the original variable before the increment.  So the value of j++ is 1. And i will get this value. At the same time j will be incressed and get value 2.